# CSS selector and border issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to achieve the following with my code:

Issue (a) Change only `Click Here` to be surrounded by a box.

Issue (b) The border for the box in (a) should disappear and reappear.

Currently, I face the following issues with my code:

**Issue (a)**

For (a), my code does not just change `Click Here` to be surrounded by a box. It also changes `Pinterest` to be surrounded by a box. I believe the issue is with selecting the top level `ul` but I have not succeeded in doing so.

*Relevant CSS code*

```
.cover-buttons ul:first-of-type li:nth-last-child(5) a {
  color: black;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 14px 18px!important;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 17px;
  font-size: 12px;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: all .2s ease;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 2px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  list-style-type: none;
  font-family: 'Varela Round', 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}
```

**Issue (b)**

For (b), I can't seem to get the box border to blink.

*Relevant Javascript code*

```
$(function(){
        var count = 0, $input = jQuery('.buttons.medium.button-outlined').not('.add-review, .bookmark, .show-dropdown, .sn-share'), interval = setInterval(function() {
            if ($input.hasClass('blur')) {
                $input.removeClass('blur').addClass('focus'); ++count;
            } else {
                $input.removeClass('focus').addClass('blur');
            }
            if (count === 3) { clearInterval(interval); }
        }, 2000);
});
```

*Relevant CSS code*

```
.focus {
  border: 1px solid white;
}

.blur {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

The strange thing about issue (b) is that it seems to work when I change the `background-color` as shown here: https://jsfiddle.net/75nvLs4x/12/. However, when I try to modify the `border thickness` it does not work.

Full script including HTML is included here: https://jsfiddle.net/75nvLs4x/14/

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Is there some reason why you are targeting it with .cover-buttons ul li:nth-last-child(5) a, instead of just giving it a class?

Comment: @VilleKoo I am using a wordpress theme. Thus, I believe I need to work with the file structure of the theme? I am new to this so please do let me know if I am wrong. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Issue A**

Your selector is: `.cover-buttons ul li:nth-last-child(5) a` this will affect any `ul` inside `.cover-buttons`. As there are two `ul`s that have `li:nth-last-child(5)`, both have the `li:nth-last-child` applied.

You can fix this by saying only the `ul` that's directly inside `.cover-buttons` and only the `li` directly inside that `ul`

```
.cover-buttons > ul > li:nth-last-child(5) a
```

---

**Issue B**

Your border issue is due to specificity - the border in the `.cover-buttons ul li:nth-last-child(5) a` section is more specific than just `.focus` so is always used.  You *could* add `!important` to the border inside `.focus`, but that's not best practice - instead, remove the border from the main block and it works fine.

Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/75nvLs4x/18/